# ParseException: Unparseable date error trying to parse a date from csv (windows)

Tags: java, scala, date, csv

I have a program that is parsing a csv file and I use it to do some actions based on the csv data for each line.

The funny thing is, on mac the program run good and it use to run on windows perfectly as well, but from some reason now when I run it on windows I get this error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "27-Nov-14"
>           at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>           at controllers.PurchaseInfo$.controllers$PurchaseInfo$$changeDateFormat(
>   PurchaseInfo.scala:44)
>   ~[play-scala.play-scala-1.1%20SNAPSHOT-sans-externalized. jar:na]

There is no different in the date format. I didnt changes anything I dont have any idea why there is an error.

this is my PurchaseInfo func for formatting the date:

```
private def changeDateFormat(dateInString: String): String = {
  //System.out.println(dateInString)
  //val formatter: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy")
  val formatter: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy")
  val formatter2: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
  val date: Date = formatter.parse(dateInString)
  return formatter2.format(date).toString
```

please help, let me know what pieces of the code you need to understand more...

Comment: your formatter2 expects the date to be 27/11/14  . Your date is 27-Nov-14 . Format exception. Remove formatter2, use formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your Windows machine has English locale.

You can specify the locale in the SimpleDateFormat constructor to avoid this kind of problems:

```
val formatter: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
```